# Purpose of Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, azure-ml, search

Azure provides a service called *Cognitive Search* which is an intelligent AI-based search service based on advanced NLP.

I tried this feature. And to make the search as efficient as possible, it requires lot of configuration to be done, such as, applying filters like sortable, filterable, facetable, searchable, enabling spell check, adding synonyms, etc. Also, it gives decent results only when tried on data rich in text. It fails at searching through data rich in numbers.

How is this an inteliigent search service when everything needs to be specified manually?